# Value of R in reverse voltage protection circuit based on PMOS

Tags: circuit-design, pmos, reverse-polarity

How do I choose the value of **R2** in this circuit? (V = 12V, I = 2A)

For the PMOS I am using SI2323DDS-T1-GE3 ([Datasheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/64004/si2323dds.pdf)), is it to ok to use this PMOS (Maximum Power Dissipation=1.7W)?

For the Zener diode I will use MMSZ5236B-7-F [Datasheet](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds18010.pdf).

[image]

Comment: C8 is present for a reason and its time constant is dependent on R2 so, changing R2 will have a knock-on effect on some inrush speed (maybe) so you probably shouldn't change it (given what details you have provided in your question).

Comment: @Andyaka I will not add C8. many designs  does not include it.

Comment: For the MOSFET you want to use, you'll have to rethink the value of the zener diode.

Comment: @Andyaka for the pmos Vgsmax=8V and the Vz=7.88max for the zener diode. I am not using the same components in the circuit.

Comment: I suggest that now is the time to update your circuit to prevent others going down the same path and avoiding wasting people's time. Circuits are the main thing folk look at.

Comment: @Andyaka---Done--- Can you please check the power dissipation of the PMOS.

Comment: I thought your question was about choosing R2 and not checking the power dissipation of the MOSFET

Comment: @Andyaka Yes I got confused on the selection of the resistor. I am asking you about your opinion if you don't mind I want to double check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *for the pmos Vgsmax=8V and the Vz=7.88max for the zener diode.*

I wouldn't want to sail that close to 8 volts. I'd be thinking about a 6.2 volt zener. With a 6.2 volt zener (MMSZ5234B) the maximum voltage is 6.51 volts at a test current of 20 mA. And there's the main point; you select your resistor so that at the maximum supply voltage (say 14 volts), there won't be more than 20 mA flowing into the zener i.e. no chance of the voltage creeping up toward 8 volts.

In other words I'm applying a little bit of headroom to the situation. The resistor value will be: -

$$\dfrac{14 - 6.51}{20 mA} = 374.5 Ω$$

I'd choose a 390 Ω resistor. Then I'd double check the MOSFET data sheet so that its power dissipation won't be excessive given the lowest value load you might want to use.